# PyCharm/Django Setup: cannot import charset from email?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I've been asked to contribute to some in-production Python/Django code. I'm setting it up in PyCharm. When I run the app, I get this error message:

```
File "/myApp/myVirtualEnvironment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py",
 line 8, in <module>
  from email import (charset as Charset, encoders as Encoders)
   ImportError: cannot import name charset
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may be caused by the [name shadowing trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap).

A cause may be that you are shadowing the [Charset class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.charset.html#email.charset.Charset), which is defined in the email.charset module, when you import `from email import (charset as Charset, encoders as Encoders)`.

Another probable cause, supported by [this issue](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206594905-SOLVED-ImportError-cannot-import-name-modname?sort_by=votes): 
If you check your file tree, you may find a file named `charset.py` or `Charset.py` which shadows the above mentioned

Search your files and you will find what casts the shadow.

Comment: Thanks, John. Should I look for a file named email.py, or charset.py?

Comment: That is usually the problem that causes this error, something that shadows an official python module.